# Run compiled Java code before APK packaging

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My app shows a list of items created from a static XML file contained in the APK. To speed things up, my app caches a binary version of the data on the first load. The app starts around 300ms faster when it reads the cached binary data rather than the XML.

You can guess where this is going: I want to precompute the binary version when the app is built and stick that into the `assets` directory. I'd like to keep the XML loader because users can select other XML files and show those in the app. So I don't want to move my loader into `buildSrc`, or go through the effort of building a separate project for both the build scripts and app to depend on.

I've gotten gradle to run my caching code as a separate target, but I don't know which Android build task to declare a `doLast` on for it to happen during a normal build.

Which task should I declare the dependency on, so it's generated whenever a build runs? I've tried `preBuild`, `packageDebug`, and `packageRelease`.

```
task writeBinary() {
    doFirst {
        print("Writing binary file")
        javaexec {
            classpath += files("build/intermediates/classes/debug")
            classpath += files("build_libs/xpp3-1.1.4c.jar")
            main = "ehues.tome.loader.BinaryReaderWriter"
            args = ['src/main/assets/standard/my.xml', 'src/main/assets/standard/my.bin']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is in general a questionable approach; just don't use `assets` or `res/raw` and have your resources automatically processed by [AAPT2](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) - instead of attempting to re-invent the wheel.

The point is, that `assets` and `res/raw` are not being processed, but only copied.

And if you really would like to create binary format, this can be done by running `aapt2` or `aapt2.exe`. A Gradle `Exec` task can run a terminal command - and such task then can be added to the graph:

```
aapt2 compile path-to-input-files [options] -o output-directory/
```

However, providing proper resource XML format would cause it to handle this all by itself.

Comment: I don't see docs on reading flat files generated by AAPT2 - is AAPT2 intended to be used for domain data, or just the Android SDK?

Comment: @Erigami you'll get a [TypedArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray) when reading that binary format; think this is Android specific (since the AAPT2 tool, which compiled the resources, is Android specific, already).